# How to deploy my own little network with some Tezos nodes on Docker just for research?

Tags: node, docker, testing

I'd like to run some Tezos nodes in my private Docker network just for studying baking process and principles of blockchain in practice. But all instructions I could find are about how to connect main network using real cryptocurrency. Can anyone share some links with instructions or explain me how to do it?

P.S. I know, that this question goes against some SO rules, but I just I can't ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Flextesa](https://assets.tqtezos.com/docs/setup/2-sandbox/)

In a docker-compose file, it should look like the following:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  sandbox:
    image: tqtezos/flextesa:20210316
    command: edobox start -P 8732
    container_name: sandbox
    environment:
      block_time: 1
      TEZOS_CLIENT_UNSAFE_DISABLE_DISCLAIMER: Y
    ports:
      - "8732:8732"
```

It will bake a block every second and you can query the rpc at `http://localhost:8732`

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! Of course, I'll read all docs, but can you say me briefly, are there any significant differencies between protocol used by Flextesa and protocol used by Tezos mainnet?

Comment: It runs the same protocol as mainnet, which is "EDO" but with different constants (seconds per block, etc...)

But it can run exactly the same constants too.

Comment: Thanks again for such quick answers. You helped me a lot :)